# How can I parse this xFBML invite-form in my iframe facebook app?

Tags: javascript, debugging, facebook, fbml

I got a Facebook canvas apps that already works for authentification on server side and client side. I can post on the wall of my user, and run my app in the canvas fine.

I wanted to add a 'invite your friends' page, and followed the doc by creating a xFBML form:

```
[...]
<div id='invite-friends-form'>
     <fb:serverfbml style="width: 650px;"> 
            <script type="text/fbml">  
                <fb:fbml> 
                  <fb:request-form
                    action="http://www.myapp.com:8080//invite/"
                    method="POST"
                    invite="true"
                    type="Name of my app"
                    content="My app description
                      <fb:req-choice url='http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/'
                      label='Accept'
                      /> 
                    " > 
                    <fb:multi-friend-selector
                      showborder="false"
                      actiontext="Invite your friends to my app"
                      rows="4"
                    > <fb:multi-friend-selector />
                  </fb:request-form> 
                </fb:fbml>
            </script> 
        </fb:serverfbml> 
</div>

<div id='fb-root'></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js"></script>
<!-- This does nothing so I commented it out. Can't find a way to debug
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.debug.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://myapp.com:8080/js/my_app_js.js"></script>

</html>
```

This xFBML renders fine when tested in their [test page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/).

Now, in my iframe, I got nothing but the facebook loading animation displaying forever.

Here is my Javascript. I use jQuery to run the code once DOM is ready:

```
$(function(){

  FB.init({
     appId  : 'my_app_id',
     status : true, 
     cookie : true, 
     xfbml  : true,
     level  : "debug"
   });


     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

         if (response.session) {
             // logged in and connected user, someone you know

             alert('logged in'); // this always show up

                 FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('invite-friends-form'),
                function(e) {alert(e)}
                );
             alert('after xfmbl parsing'); // this sometime show up

         }
     });

[...]
```

I got no error showing up, and can't find anyway to debug this. I feel stuck.

Help warmly welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

You need to fill "url" and "domain name" in the internet site section of your app settings with url being the full web url (not the canvas one) and domain should be something like "mysite.com".